# django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: accounts_myuser.password

Tags: django-admin

при изменении города и языка програмирования у пользователя выводиться ошибка django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: accounts_myuser.password

файл Admin

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as BaseUserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.forms import ReadOnlyPasswordHashField
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

from accounts.models import MyUser


class UserCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """A form for creating new users. Includes all the required
    fields, plus a repeated password."""

    password1 = forms.CharField(label="Password", widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(
        label="Password confirmation", widget=forms.PasswordInput
    )

    class Meta:
        model = MyUser
        fields = ["email",]

    def clean_password2(self):
        # Check that the two password entries match
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise ValidationError("Passwords don't match")
        return password2

    def save(self, commit=True):
        # Save the provided password in hashed format
        user = super().save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user


class UserChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """A form for updating users. Includes all the fields on
    the user, but replaces the password field with admin's
    disabled password hash display field.
    """

    password = ReadOnlyPasswordHashField()

    class Meta:
        model = MyUser
        fields = ["email", "password", "is_active", "is_admin"]


class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    # The forms to add and change user instances
    form = UserChangeForm
    add_form = UserCreationForm

    # The fields to be used in displaying the User model.
    # These override the definitions on the base UserAdmin
    # that reference specific fields on auth.User.
    list_display = ["email", "is_admin", "language", "city", "send_email"]
    list_filter = ["is_admin"]
    fieldsets = [
        (None, {"fields": ["email", "password"]}),
        ('Settings', {"fields": ["language", "city", "send_email"]}),
        ("Permissions", {"fields": ["is_admin"]}),
    ]
    # add_fieldsets is not a standard ModelAdmin attribute. UserAdmin
    # overrides get_fieldsets to use this attribute when creating a user.
    add_fieldsets = [
        (
            None,
            {
                "classes": ["wide"],
                "fields": ["email", "password1", "password2"],
            },
        ),
    ]
    search_fields = ["email"]
    ordering = ["email"]
    filter_horizontal = ()


# Now register the new UserAdmin...
admin.site.register(MyUser, UserAdmin)
# ... and, since we're not using Django's built-in permissions,
# unregister the Group model from admin.
admin.site.unregister(Group)
```

файл Models

```
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager

from django.db import models

class MyUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, password=None):
        """
        Creates and saves a User with the given email, date of
        birth and password.
        """
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("Users must have an email address")

        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email)
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password=None):
        """
        Creates and saves a superuser with the given email, date of
        birth and password.
        """
        user = self.create_user(
            email,
            password=password,
        )
        user.is_admin = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name="email address",
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
    )
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    city = models.ForeignKey('scraping.City', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    language = models.ForeignKey('scraping.Language', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    send_email = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    objects = MyUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = "email"
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        "Does the user have a specific permission?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        "Does the user have permissions to view the app `app_label`?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        "Is the user a member of staff?"
        # Simplest possible answer: All admins are staff
        return self.is_admin
```

подскажите что не так,
через базу данные меняються нормально

Comment: вопрос решился просто заменой django3 на django 4

Answer (score 0):

вопрос решился просто заменой django3 на django 4